# remainder of bit array division C++

Tags: c++, arrays, bit

I have two bit arrays of length 200 and 10 respectively. I would like to divide the first one with second and get the remainder. How can I do it in C++ using bit operations instead of converting them to decimal and using modulo ?

Comment: An example would go along way. Are the "bit arrays" represented as 200 integers with values of 1 and 0 respectively, or do you mean 200 bits _packed_ into 32-bit integers?

Comment: Long division. It's easier to do in binary than decimal, because for each digit there's only two choices: it goes into it (1), or it doesn't (0).

Comment: I basically convert a string of length 200 to a bit array. Some characters are '1' and others are '0'.

Comment: @MarkRansom can you please explain little more about long division?

Comment: Do you just want the remainder, Or do you need the quotient as well?

Comment: @ChristopherOicles  only the remainder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation with std::bitset.

Finding the remainder involves shifting the divisor left until it is greater than or equal to the dividend, then begin shifting it back to the right, until it is at its original position. For each new value of the shifted divisor, if it is greater than the running remainder (which starts off as the dividend), subtract it to get a new remainder.  If the divisor is ever equal to the remainder, return 0. Once the divisor reaches its origiginal, unshifted position, after being subtracted from the remainder, if needed, then the remainder is finished.

The `BsMod` function takes dividend and divisor arguments, and the dividend argument is replaced with the remainder, in-place, so make sure that argument is an lvalue so you can get the result.

The default test (in main) randomly creates binary strings and prints out the binary result.  This is kind of difficult to verify, so I made another random test (`Test()`) which uses integer values for automatic varification of the result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

// subtracts b from a, replacing a with the result
template <typename A, typename B>
void Subtract(A &a, const B &b) {
    static const std::size_t minc = a.size() < b.size() ? a.size() : b.size();
    bool borrow = false;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i<minc; ++i) {
        const bool dif = a[i] ^ b[i] ^ borrow;
        borrow = (a[i] && b[i] && borrow) || (!a[i] && (b[i] || borrow));
        a[i] = dif;
    }
    for(std::size_t i=minc; borrow && i<a.size(); ++i) {
        a[i] = borrow = !a[i];
    }
}

// Returns the index of the highest set bit in b
// Returns unsigned -1 if all bits are 0
template <typename B>
std::size_t HiBit(const B& b) {
    for(std::size_t i = b.size()-1; i+1; --i) {
        if(b[i]) return i;
    }
    // b is zero
    return ~std::size_t(0);
}

// Compare returns 1 if a>b, 0 if a==b or -1 if a<b
template <typename B>
int Compare(const B &a, const B &b) {
    const std::size_t high = a.size()-1;
    for(std::size_t i=high; i+1; --i) {
        if(a[i] != b[i]) {
            return int(a[i]) - int(b[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// nr is changed from the dividend to the remainder
template <typename B>
void BsMod(B &nr, B d) {
    const std::size_t hi_n = HiBit(nr);
    const std::size_t hi_d = HiBit(d);
    if(hi_d > hi_n) return;                            // nr < d, keep n as r
    if(hi_d == hi_n && Compare(nr, d) == -1) return;   // nr < d, keep n as r

    const std::size_t dshift = hi_n - hi_d;
    d <<= dshift;

    for(std::size_t i=0; i<=dshift; ++i) {
        const int cmp = Compare(nr, d);
        if(cmp == 0) { nr = B(); return; } // d evenly divides nr, so r is 0
        if(cmp > 0) {  // nr > shifted d
            // the quotient would accumulate a 1 bit here, at the d shift position
            Subtract(nr, d);
        }
        d >>= 1;   // divide d by 2, shift back toward original position
    }
}

template <typename B>
unsigned long long bs_to_ull(const B& b) {
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    for(std::size_t i=0; i<sizeof(unsigned long long)*8; ++i) {
        result |= static_cast<unsigned long long>(b[i]) << i;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename B>
void ull_to_bs(B& b, unsigned long long n) {
    b.reset();
    for(std::size_t i=0; i<sizeof(unsigned long long)*8; ++i) {
        if(n & ((unsigned long long)1 << i)) b.set(i, true);
    }
}

unsigned long long rand_ull() {
    unsigned long long r = 0;
    unsigned long long b = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(unsigned long long); ++i) {
        r = r * 33 + rand();
        b ^= rand();
        b <<= 8;
    }
    return ((r << sizeof(unsigned long long)*4) | (r >> sizeof(unsigned long long )*4)) ^ b;
}

void Test(unsigned long long max=0, int max_iters=0) {
    typedef unsigned long long uit;
    typedef std::bitset<sizeof(unsigned long long)*8+8> bs;
    typedef unsigned long long uit;

    int iter_count = 0;
    for(;;) {
        uit a = rand_ull();
        uit b = rand_ull();
        if(max) {
            a %= max;
            b %= max;
        }
        if(rand() & 255) {
            while(b > a) b >>= rand() & 3;
        }
        if(!b) continue;

        bs bsa;
        ull_to_bs(bsa, a);
        bs bsb;
        ull_to_bs(bsb, b);

        BsMod(bsa, bsb);

        uit ibsm = bs_to_ull(bsa);
        uit m = a % b;

        std::cout << a << " % " << b << " = " << m << "    :    " << ibsm << '\n';

        if(ibsm != m) {
            std::cout << "Error\n";
            return;
        }

        ++iter_count;
        if(max_iters && iter_count > max_iters) break;
    }
}

std::string RandomBinaryString(unsigned bit_count) {
    std::string binstr;
    for(unsigned i=0; i<bit_count; ++i) {
        binstr +=  ((rand() >> (i%5)) ^ i) & 1 ?  '1' : '0';
    }
    return binstr;
}

void TrimLeadingZeros(std::string& s) {
    if(s.length() < 2 || s[0] != '0') return;
    for(std::string::size_type i=1; i<s.length()-1; ++i) {
        if(s[i] != '0') {
            s = s.substr(i);
            return;
        }
    }
    s = s.substr(s.length()-1);
}

int main() {
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    //Test(0, 10);  // test with integer values (which are easy to auto-validate)
    //return 0;

    std::string a = RandomBinaryString(200);
    std::string b = RandomBinaryString(10);

    static const int max_bitount = 220;
    typedef std::bitset<max_bitount> bs;

    bs bsa(a);
    bs bsb(b);

    // both arguments must have the same type (number of bits)
    // bsa gets replaced with bsa modulo bsb
    BsMod(bsa, bsb); 


    std::string c = bsa.to_string();
    TrimLeadingZeros(c);

    std::cout << a << "\n   mod\n" << b << "\n   ==\n" << c << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thanks !! I got your logic. I get of compile errors when I use your code. That's because of template. I am kind of not familiar with that.

Comment: @SBDK8219 What compiler do you use?

Comment: The gcc version is  gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313. I also tried C++11 like this $ g++ -std=c++0x your_file.cpp -o your_program

Comment: Hmm, it must be complaining about the `<random>` library and maybe `auto` variables.  I'll have a new version in a little while that's more compatible.

Comment: I was testing with the IdeOne C++14  compiler, as well as Visual C++ 2013.  I'm about to make an edit which should fix your problems.  Just a sec...

Comment: Ok, I made the changes!

Answer (score 1):

I would first take a look at using [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). This appears like it could be easier to use than arrays. Secondly read up on articles about using bitwise operations to perform modulo. One of such articles I found was [this](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1946). Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks !! I was looking for something like this. I will try this for sure.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Answer (score 0):

At first define the shifted subtraction for your two type of numbers ( 200 bit and 10 bit ). Afterwards prosecute to the division.